# CSS Grid: How to have an item that span across all columns and auto-fit the others across the remaining space

Tags: html, css

I would like to have a title spanning across the full-width and on row below have columns that fit the full-width as well.

In the following example, I was expecting the FOO and BAR to take the full width of the screen (50% each), but as soon as the viewport is exceeding 300px, the grid creates empty columns.

```html
<div style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));">
  <h1 style="grid-column: 1 / -1; border: 1px solid black;">TITLE</h1>
  <div style="background-color: red;">FOO</div>
  <div style="background-color: green;">BAR</div>
</div>
```

Here is the result:

[image: result]

And here is what I was expecting

[image: expected]

Do you know why the auto-fit property isn't working ?

Comment: this is the purpose of auto-fit ... it seems that you simpy need to define 2 columns: `grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr`

Comment: See here: https://css-tricks.com/auto-sizing-columns-css-grid-auto-fill-vs-auto-fit

Answer (score 1):

The grid-column: 1 / -1; is breaking the css

Only put elements that will be auto placed inside repeat block

```html
<h1 style="width : 100%; border: 1px solid black;">TITLE</h1>
<div style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));">
  <div style="background-color: red;">FOO</div>
  <div style="background-color: green;">BAR</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I included titles in the grid because I want all div to be the same size.
In the example below, I want the div under TITLE 1 to be the same width than the div under TITLE2:

```
<div style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(125px, 1fr));">
    <h2 style="grid-column: 1 / -1; border: 1px solid black;">TITLE 1</h2>
    <div style="background-color: red;">FOO</div>
    <div style="background-color: green;">BAR</div>
    
    <h2 style="grid-column: 1 / -1; border: 1px solid black;">TITLE 2</h2>
    <div style="background-color: red;">FOO</div>
</div>
```